# How to display bing wallpaper in my wpf app?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to show background image of my WPF application from bing wallpaper, in order to every time when application launches I will have new bing image.

Comment: what does your mean about bing wallpaper ?!

Answer (score 1):

if you meant to get www.bing.com webpage the bing backgroud image; you may use webbrowser object (visible at false) which must run at background at open www.bing.com page, and from Page Source it may take the image link and save it on local disc. After all you can display it where you want

may look : [WebBrowser Class at C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

Comment: You can get the background link like `g_img={url:'/fd/hpk2/HappisburghUK_EN-US493145329.jpg'}`, so, you can use this url to get the image.(with DownloadFile method from System.Net.WebClient class.) Image link is like this : `http://www.bing.com/fd/hpk2/HappisburghUK_EN-US493145329.jpg`

Comment: You should have made it answer not comment :)